# Can't bind to 'pTooltip' since it isn't a known property of 'button' in angular PrimeNG

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am use **`Angular 16`**
And I use `primgn16` for the project

I actually got this error when migrating Angular from version **12** to version **16**
This worked well in version 12 of the project

Maybe this photo will convey my meaning better

[image]

Of course, I tried with this method and the problem was still the same

```
[pTooltip]="{{ 'COMMON.Refresh' | translate }}"
```

or

```
[pTooltip]=" ('COMMON.Refresh' | translate )"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that you are having the `TooltipModule` imported in the same place, this component is declared inside a module! if its a standalone component, then you need to add the `TooltipModule` to the imports array.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

import { TooltipModule } from 'primeng/tooltip';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/inputtext';
import { RippleModule } from 'primeng/ripple';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TooltipModule,
    ButtonModule,
    RippleModule,
    InputTextModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

[primeng tooltip stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tooltip-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: @davoodbeheshti You're welcome!